# Composite Template Signing Email

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am experiencing a problem where an envelope made with composite templates won't send a signing email to the recipient. I've tried multiple email accounts on several different domains, and none work. Interestingly an email IS sent when I void the envelope. I have also tried to request the signing link through the API but receive various errors. My request is below.

What I am trying to do is assemble an envelope from multiple templates. Each template has tabs that need to be filled. There are also multiple roles per template, but I have only addressed the first role here.

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "templateId": "Template1Id"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "value": "Person Jones",
                      "tabLabel": "Name_Tab"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "name": "Name",
                "email": "Email",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "clientUserId": "12345",
                "routingOrder": 1,
                "roleName": "Role 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 2,
          "templateId": "Template2Id"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 2,
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "value": "Hello",
                      "tabLabel": "World_Tab"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "name": "Name",
                "email": "Email",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "clientUserId": "12345",
                "routingOrder": 1,
                "roleName": "Role 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `clientUserId` [property](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters) for the recipient. This means you are creating an [embedded recipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html).

Emails will be sent only to remote recipients. If you remove the clientUserId parameter the recipient will get the emails.